# Buffer to base64 format for pdf

Tags: node.js, xero-api

When I run getAsPDF on the Xero side, I get a buffer output like this:

[image]

I am trying to convert it to base64 format and send it as pdf, but I could not convert it to pdf format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass the buffer data to Buffer object to convert data into base64.

Link: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding

Example:

`const base64Data = Buffer.from(bufferDataGoesHere).toString("base64");`